# how do I pass a variable as key into a javascript unshift/push?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I'm trying to set a variable name in an `unshift()` call like so:

```
var new_index_name = priv.indices[i]["name"], // e.g. "container"
    new_index_array.unshift({new_index_name :[]});
```

But my new_index_array will now contain:

```
[ {new_index_name : []} ]
```

instead of

```
[ {"container" : []} ]
```

**Question:**
Is it possible to pass a variable name as the `key` value in a push/unshift call?

Thanks for help!

Comment: I think you meant ; at the end of the first line of code

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This has nothing to do with `push` or `unshift`

You can't use a variable as a property in an object literal (since you can use identifiers for property names, and variables are also represented by identifiers).

You have to construct the object, then add the data to it.

```
var new_index_name = priv.indices[i]["name"], // e.g. "container"
var ob = {};
    ob[new_index_name] = [];
    new_index_array.unshift(ob);
```